# Which Hypothesis Test should I apply in this case?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

A system produces samples. I have historical data as thousands of samples. I know the number of samples, their mean and their standard deviation. This data was collected by using the same system.

But recently the system was modified. And I have around 30 new samples after the system update. I know the number of new samples, their mean and their standard deviation.

I want to make a test by using null hypothesis and verify if the system update had any significant effect or not.

I’m confused between many different types of tests. Some are use when standard deviation of the population is not known, some use one-tail ect.
In my case I have all the historical samples and the new samples; I have means and standard deviations of both.

Which test should I apply in this case? (I'm almost novice in the field)

Comment: One reason for the existence of so many tests is that the world has an infinite variety of behaviors.  Some aspects that could be important in your case are (1) the distribution of the sample results, (2) the possibility of temporal correlation, and (3) the nature of the sample data.  It would be unprofessional (and possibly wrong and harmful) to give any blanket advice without ascertaining more about these issues.  Please, then, update your post to provide relevant information.

Comment: there can be millions of information. tell me what kind of info you need more.

Comment: I did, explicitly: tell us about *distributions,* the *potential for temporal correlation,* and *type of data measurement.*

Answer (score 0):

I think that a single sample Z-test would be appropriate as you suggest that the samples that you are in possession of have a mean and standard deviation. Conceptually, you would be treating the population of samples which you have as a true population. It's mean would be equal to the mean of all the samples' means. Then test your new sample's mean against this population using the Z-test formula:
Z = (your sample mean - known population mean)/(standard deviation of the population/(SQRT(size of new sample)).

This test would tell you if the new system deviates from the old one in producing samples with a different than expected mean.

Comment: *Any* test can tell you whether there has been a change.  The issue is whether its information is *reliable.*  What characteristics of this situation can you point to that indicate a Z-test would give reliable results?